# Unable to install php5.5 apcu module on Debian 6.0 server

Tags: php, php5, alternative-php-cache

Since APC is not supported by PHP 5.5 as an OP code cache I read that I can still use APC for user data which sounds good for me. It's called APCu and it should be compatible with the old APC.

Unfortunatelly, I'm not able to install it in any way. Running:

```
apt-get install php5-apcu
```

will end wit error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-apcu : Depends: phpapi-20100525
             Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.26-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.5.10+dfsg-1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I thought maybe I can install it via PECL, but throws error during compilation:

```
/tmp/pear/temp/apcu/apc_cache.c:359: error: '}' expected (got ",")
make: *** [apc_cache.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Have anyone managed to install APCu?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the dotdeb.org repository for your old PHP, and some other repository for PHP 5.5. The other repository doesn't have `php5-apcu` package available, therefore it tries to use PHP 5.4 package for it.

The solution is to use dotdeb.org's PHP 5.5 repository to install your PHP 5. This repository should also contain the `php5-apcu` package you want. To install dotdeb.org's PHP 5 repository, add these two lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 all
```